# is it good to leave pg_stat_statements permanently on production servers?

Tags: postgresql, monitoring

I am fairly new to Postgresql (coming from SQL Server)

I came across that package and it looks very interesting.

Is it good practice to leave it on permanently on production servers?

On one hand, I want to know what actually loads my system in production.
On the other hand, I don't want to load my server by monitoring either...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I always enable it on production databases. The benefits are well worth the small performance hit.

Particularly on a production database you want to know which statements cause the most pain and should be optimized.

Comment: I expected that answer as this is what I would do on SQL Server too.
Thanks for confirming